# Как через переменную указать столбец таблицы?

Tags: python

Я работаю с sqlite3 в Python. У меня задача - через переменную указать курсору какой выбрать столбец таблицы.

Я решил попробовать:

```
db.execute("SELECT (?) FROM my_db", [a]).fetchall()
```

Но в результате вместо значения 0, я получаю имя указанного столбца.

Как мне правильно реализовать мою задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для столбцов параметрическая подстановка невозможна. Если вы доверяете своим переменным, то можно просто подставить значение обычным образом, например через f-строку:

```py
db.execute(f"SELECT {a} FROM my_db").fetchall()
```

Это небезопасный метод, но для столбцов, повторюсь, нормальные безопасные методы не работают.